# Replay stream of events with correct timing in javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

An user "A", performs a series of events in a browser window, let's keep it simple for now, just keys pressed.

This series of events is sent to the server through websocket and broadcasted to all connected clients.

All the connected clients see the same series of events happening in their browser window with the correct timing, so for example if the user A presses the key 'a', waits 2 seconds, then presses the key 'b', I want that the 2 seconds delay is replicated in the connected clients.

Also, the timing between key strokes could be potentially very short (20ms) so, I'd like the system to be very accurate.

I came up with this idea of "sampling" the events, basically have a `setInterval` loop running every 10ms which stores in an array a sequence like this:

```
[{key: 'none'}, {key: 'none'}, {key: 'a'}, {key: 'a'}, {key: 'none'}, {key: 'none'}, {key: 'b'}...]
```

The array is then sent to the listening clients through websokets and on the clients a similar 10ms `setInterval` loop goes through the event array "replaying it".

Do you have any better ideas in order to achieve this?

NOTE: I'm deliberately ignoring network latency at the moment

Comment: event objects have a timestamp - no need for polling

Comment: cool, no sampling on the transmitting client, but how would you replay it on the receiving clients using the timestamps? still using setInterval but with variable delay?